# XSLT transforming sibling by index

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert following XML

```
<a>Street1</a>
<a>Street2</a>
<a>Street3</a>
<c>zip1</c>
<c>zip2</c>
<c>zip3</c>
<b>city1</b>
<b>city2</b>
<b>city3</b>
```

to below result

```
<a>Street1</a><b>city1</b><c>zip1</c>
<a>Street2</a><b>city2</b><c>zip2</c>
<a>Street3</a><b>city3</b><c>zip3</c>
```

The relation between   and  is by index. First Street belongs to First Zip and First City.

I have tried using nested for-each with position() but not getting desired results.

Any suggestions

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the XSLT you have currently tried. You never know, you might not be that far off a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using nested for-each with position() but not getting
>   desired results.

Only use `xsl:for-each` if a template-based solution does not make sense. Templating comes much more natural to XSLT, since it is a *functional* programming language.

Using `position()` is a good idea, though. So, the stylesheet below defines different templates (without `xsl:for-each`) and uses positional information.

**XML Input**

The input XML to an XSLT transformation must necessarily be a well-formed XML document. Among other things, this means that it must have a single document (or "root") element. The solution below assumes the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>Street1</a>
    <a>Street2</a>
    <a>Street3</a>
    <c>zip1</c>
    <c>zip2</c>
    <c>zip3</c>
    <b>city1</b>
    <b>city2</b>
    <b>city3</b>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::c[$pos]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::b[$pos]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a>Street1</a>
   <c>zip1</c>
   <b>city1</b>
   <a>Street2</a>
   <c>zip2</c>
   <b>city2</b>
   <a>Street3</a>
   <c>zip3</c>
   <b>city3</b>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it can help you.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <a><xsl:apply-templates/></a>                
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::b[$pos]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::c[$pos]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>            
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```